# Spring Flux stage execute on a different thread when using reactive redis template

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-redis, lettuce

When one of the intermediate stage uses reactive Redis template the thread in the subsequent stage changes.

1. Does it mean reactive redis template has its own scheduler? Which effects every stage moving forward.
2. If the first point is true, then should I be switching to my own scheduler for processing afterwards?.

Code example

```
        return Flux.fromArray(new String[]{"1", "2", "3"}).map(s -> s.toUpperCase()).flatMap(s -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(s, s);
    }).map(aBoolean -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return aBoolean.booleanValue();
    }).log();
```

The first map function print outputs reactor-http-nio-3.
The second map function executes in lettuce-nioEventLoop-5-1.

Comment: Yes, it switches threads. As long as you don't block it there's not much to worry about.

Comment: the reactor framework is free to switch threads whenever it feels, its the whole purpose of reactive. So if it feels it needs to switch threads to optimize the usage it will do so.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi it switches to the same thread that is managed by reactive redis? So I am doing processing on those managed thread which should only be used by reactive redis?

Comment: Yes, it is a thread managed by the redis lib, but I'm not aware of any recommendation that you should not use those threads. However, Lettuce has a publishOnScheduler option which might be useful if you are concerned about performance: https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#client-options